# change wowza video stream default server info

Tags: video-streaming, wowza

Okay so I'm new to the Wowza Streaming Engine, and I've gone through some of their tutorials and such, but I haven't found where they set the default `Server` and `Stream Name`. The page I have when I load it up has a default server of `rtmp://localhost/webcamrecording`  and the default video is `flv:webcamrecording`.  I don't see where those settings would be set or changed.  How can I have these changed to a different set (`Server` & `Stream Name`) when the page loads.

I'm basically using the sample page that comes with the Wowza downloads.

any help would be greatly appreciated.  Please let me know if any information is missing or if anything needs clarification.

Answer (score 0):

`Server` is the IP address or url of your Wowza server, and `Stream Name` is whatever the client names their stream or the name of the stream they want to connect to. There aren't any defaults. It all depends on your setup.

Comment: I understand what the `Server` and `Stream Name` are, I was just trying to figure out how to start off with the `Server` being populated with my server's IP and to provide an initial `Stream Name` for the case of giving the user a video to watch, because I have two different cases: 1. they watch a video; 2. they record a video.  I'll have to check how things are set up.  thanks for pointing me in that direction.